# change image onclick/run function with it image pop-up depending on winner

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a "race" going on between two pictures. The code works how I would like it to, but I want the "death.jpg" image when it is clicked on it starts the race, not when I load the page. Also I want that image to change when it is clicked on. And I want a different image to show depending on who the winner is. It just shows one single image now. The tie.jpg and x-wing.jpg are the two racing and I want the winners image to pop-up. Should I use a ... if, else if for the image? Im going to resize the images and put their locations later.

UPDATE!! --> So I have everything working how it should, image changes and all. But when the two images that are racing get to the right side of the screen, they continue to go until the image is not seen then it stops. Heres the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Race Me</title>

<style>
body { background-color: blue;
}

    div.raceTrack {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 12em;
}
img {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

.img1 {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}

.clickme {
float: right;
}

div#announce {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 10em;
width: 10em;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
.hidden {
opacity: 0;
}
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="clickme">
<input type="image" id="start" src="death.png" alt="dstar" onclick="startRace()">
<div class="raceTrack">
<img src="tie.png" id="tie-w" class="img1" alt="tie" style="left: 0px" width="40" height="20">
<hr>
<img src="xwing.png" id="x-wing" class="img1" alt="xwing" style="left: 0px" width="40">
</div>
<div id="announce" class="hidden" onclick="location.reload(true)" VALUE="Refresh">

<img id="winner">
</div>
<script>
var tie,
xWing,
tracker,
timer,
raceLength = window.innerWidth - 42;

function randomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function RaceTracker() {
this.racers = [];

this.addRacer = function (racer) {
this.racers.push(racer);
}

this.endRace = function () {
clearInterval(timer);
}

this.announce = function (racer) {
var announcer = document.getElementById("announce");
announcer.classList.remove("hidden");
setImageSrc('winner', racer.id +'.png');

}

this.isRacerAtEnd = function (bln, racer) {
if (bln === true) {
  this.endRace();
  this.announce(racer);
}
}

this.updateRacerPosition = function () {
var idx = randomInt(0, this.racers.length - 1);
this.isRacerAtEnd(this.racers[idx].updatePosition(), this.racers[idx]);
}

this.render = function () {
this.racers.forEach(function (racer) {
   racer.render();
});
}

}


function Racer(id) {
this.id = id;
this.racer = document.getElementById(this.id);
this.velocity = 25;
this.position = parseInt(this.racer.style.left, 10);

this.updatePosition = function () {
  if (this.position + this.velocity < raceLength) {
    this.position += this.velocity;
    return false;
  }

this.position = raceLength;
return true;
}

this.render = function () {
  this.racer.style.left = this.position + "px";
}
}

function startRace() {
setImageSrc('start', 'cat.png');
var announcer = document.getElementById("announce");
announcer.classList.add("hidden");

tracker = new RaceTracker();
tie = new Racer("tie-w");
xWing = new Racer("x-wing");

tracker.addRacer(tie);
tracker.addRacer(xWing);

tie.position = 0;
xWing.position = 0;
tracker.render();
race = setTimeout(startRaceTimer, 1000);
}

function run() {
tracker.updateRacerPosition();
tracker.render();
}

function startRaceTimer() {
timer = setInterval(run, 100);
}

function setImageSrc(imgId, imgFilename) {
var oImg = document.getElementById(imgId);
oImg.src = imgFilename;
oImg.alt = imgFilename;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's a working solution. I haven't re-written the code, just added to it in a similar style to make it do what's needed - it would benefit from some reworking, but that's left as an exercise for the OP =)

#### Click the Death Star to start the race

Clicking the "Death Star" calls `StartRace` (which used to be `initilize`) - this function now not only initialises everything, but also:

- changes the image for the "Death Star"
- hides the `announce` element (that displays the winner)
- resets the position of the racers

I have added a `StartRaceTimer` function to give a little delay before restarting the race - that way the timing is more natural and less abrupt.

#### Display a different image according to the winner

This was almost working, but had no code for setting the image, so I have introduced a new generic function to use for setting the source of an image, and this is used for both this and setting the "Death Star" image.

Further fun could be had by refactoring the code (remove redundant bits, combine, etc.), using better OOP, rewriting using jQuery =)

### HTML

```
<div class="clickme">
  <input type="image" id="start" src="death.png" alt="dstar" onclick="startRace()">
<div class="raceTrack">
<img src="tie.jpg" id="tie" alt="tie" style="left: 0px" width="40" height="20">
  <hr>
  <img src="xwing.jpg" id="x-wing" alt="xwing" style="left: 0px" width="40">
</div>
<div id="announce" class="hidden">
  <span id="message">and the winner is...</span>
  <img id="winner" src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever.jpg" >
</div>
```

### CSS (unchanged from original)

```
div.raceTrack {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 12em;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border: 1px solid;
}
div#announce {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #91C43B;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

### Javascript

```
var tie,
    xWing,
    tracker,
    timer,
    raceLength = window.innerWidth - 42;

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function RaceTracker() {
  this.racers = [];

  this.addRacer = function (racer) {
    this.racers.push(racer);
  }

  this.endRace = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  this.announce = function (racer) {
    var announcer = document.getElementById("announce");
    announcer.classList.remove("hidden");
    setImageSrc('winner', racer.id+'.jpg');
    setImageSrc('start', 'death.png');
  }

  this.isRacerAtEnd = function (bln, racer) {
    if (bln === true) {
      this.endRace();
      this.announce(racer);
    }
  }

  this.updateRacerPosition = function () {
    var idx = randomInt(0, this.racers.length - 1);
    this.isRacerAtEnd(this.racers[idx].updatePosition(), this.racers[idx]);
  }

  this.render = function () {
    this.racers.forEach(function (racer) {
       racer.render();
    });
  }

}


function Racer(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.racer = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.velocity = 25;
    this.position = parseInt(this.racer.style.left, 10);

    this.updatePosition = function () {
      if (this.position + this.velocity < raceLength) {
        this.position += this.velocity;
        return false;
      }

    this.position = raceLength;
    return true;
    }

    this.render = function () {
      this.racer.style.left = this.position + "px";
    }
}

function startRace() {
  setImageSrc('start', 'go.png');
  var announcer = document.getElementById("announce");
  announcer.classList.add("hidden");

  tracker = new RaceTracker();
  tie = new Racer("tie");
  xWing = new Racer("x-wing");

  tracker.addRacer(tie);
  tracker.addRacer(xWing);

  tie.position = 0;
  xWing.position = 0;
  tracker.render();
  race = setTimeout(startRaceTimer, 1000);
}

function run() {
    tracker.updateRacerPosition();
    tracker.render();
}

function startRaceTimer() {
    timer = setInterval(run, 100);
}

function setImageSrc(imgId, imgFilename) {
  var oImg = document.getElementById(imgId);
  oImg.src = imgFilename;
  oImg.alt = imgFilename;
}
```

### UPDATE

The algorithm for detecting if a racer has "won" checks the `.position` property (i.e. the `left` CSS property) of the racer against the width of the viewport (minus an arbitrary number of pixels). Strictly speaking, the racer should win if the leading edge crosses the finish line; not the trailing edge.
The update to the original code changed the width of the racer images from 40px to 200px, so now the difference between the leading and trailing edge is much greater, and it looks like the racer has gone over the edge of the screen.

I have adjusted the code to set the "finish line" at the edge of the screen (i.e. viewport width), and the check now takes the width of the racer image into consideration:

```
var tie,
    xWing,
    tracker,
    timer,
    finishLine = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function RaceTracker() {
  this.racers = [];

  this.addRacer = function (racer) {
    this.racers.push(racer);
  }

  this.endRace = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  this.announce = function (racer) {
    var announcer = document.getElementById("announce");
    announcer.classList.remove("hidden");
    setImageSrc('winner', racer.id +'.png');
  }

  this.isRacerAtEnd = function (bln, racer) {
    if (bln === true) {
      this.endRace();
      this.announce(racer);
    }
  }

  this.updateRacerPosition = function () {
    var idx = randomInt(0, this.racers.length - 1);
    this.isRacerAtEnd(this.racers[idx].updatePosition(), this.racers[idx]);
  }

  this.render = function () {
    this.racers.forEach(function (racer) {
      racer.render();
    });
  }

}


function Racer(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.racer = document.getElementById(this.id);
  this.velocity = 25;
  this.position = parseInt(this.racer.style.left, 10);

  this.updatePosition = function () {
    this.nose = this.position + parseInt(this.racer.width, 10);

    if (this.nose + this.velocity < finishLine) {
      this.position += this.velocity;
      return false;
    }

    this.position = (finishLine - this.racer.width);
    return true;
  }

  this.render = function () {
    this.racer.style.left = this.position + "px";
  }

}

function startRace() {
  setImageSrc('start', 'cat.png');
  var announcer = document.getElementById("announce");
  announcer.classList.add("hidden");

  tracker = new RaceTracker();
  tie = new Racer("tie-w");
  xWing = new Racer("x-wing");

  tracker.addRacer(tie);
  tracker.addRacer(xWing);

  tie.position = 0;
  xWing.position = 0;
  tracker.render();
  race = setTimeout(startRaceTimer, 1000);
}

function run() {
  tracker.updateRacerPosition();
  tracker.render();
}

function startRaceTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(run, 100);
}

function setImageSrc(imgId, imgFilename) {
  var oImg = document.getElementById(imgId);
  oImg.src = imgFilename;
  oImg.alt = imgFilename;
}
```